# How to stop a postback from a radpanelitem in a masterpage?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I have double checked to make sure that this isn't a duplicate question...I have a masterpage that has a side nav bar and it looks like this..

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="572px">
<telerik:RadPanelBar ID="RadPanelBar1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Vendors" Expanded="false" runat="server">
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Search Vendor" NavigateUrl="../GO_Browse_Vendors.aspx" />
                <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Add Vendor" />
                <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Update Vendor" />
                <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Delete Vendor" />
            </Items>
        </telerik:RadPanelItem>
    </Items>
</telerik:RadPanelBar>
```

when I click on Search Vendor, I get a complete postback and I really don't understand why that is happening, I want to be able to just click on an item and the page appear without having a postback.
At first I used JavaScript to open a RadWindow, and that didn't cause any postback. Then I realized, that the user will probably get lost with a bunch of Radwindows. Then I decided that I should have the Search Vendor to just be a page and use radwindows for updating a record.
I thought about using JQuery but I am at a loss on how that would work. Is there anyway I can do this without causing a postback?
I wrote this JavaScript to call a RadWindow...

```
function OnAreaClick(sender, args) {
        var menuItem = args.get_item().get_text();

        switch (menuItem) {
            case 'Search Vendor':
                {
                    OpenRadWindow2("WebForm9.aspx");
                }
            default: { }
        }
```

I'm sure that this is simple, but I am not finding it simple.

Comment: Wow, just reading over my question while I'm looking around and my question doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out...I dug around and used JQuery.Load...No postback is happening now, this is the code that I used..

```
function OnAreaClick(sender, args) {
        var menuItem = args.get_item().get_text();

        switch (menuItem) {
            case 'Search Vendor':
                {
                    GetForm("GO_Browse_Vendors.aspx");
                }
            default: { }
        }
    }
    function GetForm(url) {
        $("#RZone").load(url, {}, function () { });
    }
```